# ESXi PCI passthrough on HP DL360 G5

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, passthrough

I am running ESXi 5.5 on a DL360 G5 and the option for PCI passthrough shows 'Host does not support passthrough configuration'.

I have enabled VT in the BIOS under processor options and I have x64 guests.

Does anyone know if the DL360 G5 supports PCI passthrough or is there anything I can change to support this feature? I want to pass the graphics card installed to the VM.

Processor: Intel Xeon X5450

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks, 
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't support PCI passthrough.  The CPU/BIOS feature you require is VT**-d** or IOMMU.

The VT option you can see is to enable virtualisation extensions which are required for 64bit OS, paravirtualisation, etc. But do not include directed IO.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, the DL360 G5 does not support Intel VT Directed I/O (VT-d)